# ASP.NET MVC 3 WCF not working on load balancing servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, load-balancing

I searched the internet but couldn't find any scenarios like the one I'm having. The scenario is I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 Reporting application and stand-alone WCF hosted services. I am doing a bin deploy for ASP.NET MVC 3. Everything works great on my local environment and dev server. I am using a service reference in the ASP.NET MVC project to call into the client side proxy.

However, when I deploy to the clients test environment which is load balancing (ASP.NET and WCF layer both live on same load balancing servers), it is failing. If I run my local build and point my endpoints to their dev wcf services it works fine. It only fails when trying to launch the application from the test URL itself. I am getting the following error (edited the endpoint and service call information:

> "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while
>   receiving the HTTP response to http:[testserver]. This could be due to
>   the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could
>   also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was
>   closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest
>   request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead) --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Server stack
>   trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at
>   ReportingApp.UserClientProxy.IUser.GetUsersBetween(DateTime start,
>   DateTime end) at
>   ReportingApp.Controllers.HomeController.PopulateResultsTable(ReportingViewModel
>   vm) at ReportingApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index() at
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)"

My ASP.NET wcf configuration is as follows:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUser" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="5242880" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="5242880" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="5242880"
            maxBytesPerRead="5242880" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880" />
          <security mode="None" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="[testEndPoint]" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUser" contract="UserClientProxy.IUser"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IUser" />
```

My service web config looks like this:

```
 <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <!--Doubled from value again to resolve issues with the reporting process.-->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="524288" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="5242880" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="5242880" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="5242880"
           maxBytesPerRead="5242880" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue? Could it be a permission issue or a configuration issue? I am confused as it works from my local build pointing to the clients test environment endpoint.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm thinking, you mean you have your web service web config and your asp.net MVC web config? rather than asp.net WCF configuration?

Comment: where do you define your service endpoint?

Comment: Hi Edmund, Yes I have my asp.net mvc web config and my web service web config. My endpoint is actually pointing to the DNS server name. I was thinking this may be a firewall or the DNS rerouting the service call to another service.

Comment: Your load balancer is doing strange things to the connections, that's why you get communication exceptions. This is likely entirely relegated to the specifics of your load balancer and probably not solvable here on SO. You might be able to get help for the load balancer on serverfault. Honestly you'll likely need vendor support from your load balancer vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but we had a similar issue with my Rest services, they worked fine on our development servers, then they stopped working when we deployed them to a load balanced pool and they made a call to another service that was also on the Load Balancing Pool.

We were able to get the call to work once we turned on Source Address Translation. Our Web admin had to change the Translation setting  setting in the F5 pool to SNAT Pool. This link has more information for your network person.

https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/lc_9_x/manuals/product/lc_config_guide_10_1/lc_addrtrans.html

So this might help in the case of when a service that was working fine, is now failing when calling something that is load balanced.